# Durthang: orc castle or home of a Nazgûl?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Or would it have been just another orc infested tower like Cirith Ungol? Also would there have been many castles like Durthang in Mordor?

Comment: LOTR Wikia says it was both. It was first occupied by a Nazgul, then used as an Orc stronghold :  http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Durthang

Comment: @Richard - with all due respect to LotR Wikia, it appears to have completely fabricated most of the info it has about Durthang.

Comment: @darthsatan - Hence posted as a comment :-)

Comment: My next SFF question: which Wikia has more crap: HP or LOTR or Wookiepedia?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are only three direct references to Durthang in the texts.

The first, when Frodo and Sam are travelling through Mordor:

> A few miles north, high up in the angle where the western spur branched away from the main range, stood the old castle of Durthang, now one of the many orc-holds that clustered about the dale of Udûn.

The second, towards the end of their adventure with the Orcs:

> A troop of heavy-armed *uruks* from Barad-dûr charged into the Durthang line and threw them into confusion.

And the third, in the "Tale of Years":

> The Host of the West marches from Minas Tirith. Frodo comes in sight of the Isenmouthe; he is over-taken by Orcs on the road from Durthang to Udûn.

A fourth, indirect, reference is made by Frodo shortly after the first direct reference I cite:

> If we go on, we shall only come up to that orc-tower...

And that's it.

---

This confirms that Durthang is just another Orc-infested tower.  Tolkien doesn't provide any further information about it.

We can however surmise from the choice of phrase "now one of the many orc-holds" that Durthang was once something else, but there is no evidence or information in the books to indicate what that something else may have been.

As for other castles, we do know that the Towers of the Teeth (on either side of Cirith Gorgor) were once Gondorian strongholds which had been captured and taken over by Mordor, and it is perhaps these which the *LotR* Wikia gets its misinformation from.  Even so, these are two examples of other such castles (or at least towers).

We also know from the first direct reference I cite that Udûn was fairly well-infested compared with other Orc strongholds, but (and once again) Tolkien doesn't provide information about the nature of those other strongholds.

Comment: For completeness, there are also two references in the Appendix (Elements in Quenya and Sindarin names) to the Silmarillion, entries *dur* and *thang*, but both of these say no more than "a castle in Mordor".  There's nothing in Unfinished Tales, nothing in Rivers and Beacons, nothing anywhere else.

Comment: For further completeness, Tolkien's unfinished *Lord of the Rings* Index (quoted in *A Reader's Companion*), glosses Durthang as "Dark press or oppression".